# How to allow duplicate queries on an overpass-api custom server

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I created a custom overpass-api server running on an EC2 with Apache. Every time I run the same query twice, I get a duplicate query error.

I tried running the dispatcher with the `--allow-duplicate-queries=yes` flag, but after running the same query more than once I still get `Error: runtime error: open64: 0 Success /osm3s_osm_base Dispatcher_Client::request_read_and_idx::duplicate_query`

Comment: Can you post the exact Overpass API version you're using, e.g. 0.7.61.xx?

Comment: I'm using overpass 0.7.61 @mmd

Comment: You need to use at least 0.7.61.4 (.4 at the end is important)

Comment: Same issue is also being discussed here: https://community.openstreetmap.org/t/power-outage-corrupted-overpass-idx-files/101912/6